How do I properly model tires in Gazebo?
I created a complete URDF of a car-like robot, which I simulate in Gazebo Harmonic with the DART engine connected to ROS2 Iron. It drives around nicely, but going above 6 m/s introduces intense skidding. I tried modifying the friction physics in the following way:
<xacro:macro name="rear_wheel_lr"
    params="
      name
      parent
      reflect
      wheel_radius
      wheel_thickness
      wheel_mass
      *origin">
    <link name="${name}_wheel_link">
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_thickness}"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_thickness}"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <xacro:solid_cylinder_inertial 
          rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"
          mass="${wheel_mass}"
          radius="${wheel_radius}" length="${wheel_thickness}" />
    </link>
    <joint name="${name}_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="${parent}_link"/>
        <child link="${name}_wheel_link"/>
        <xacro:insert_block name="origin"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit effort="${max_traction_effort}"
             velocity="${max_traction_velocity}"/>
    </joint>
    <transmission name="${name}_wheel_joint_trans">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <actuator name="${name}_wheel_joint_motor">
            <mechanicalReduction>4.36</mechanicalReduction>
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </actuator>
        <joint name="${name}_wheel_joint">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
    </transmission>
    <gazebo reference="${name}_wheel_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
        <surface>
            <friction>
                <ode>
                    <mu>${friction_mu1}</mu>
                    <!-- value range 0.0 to 1.0 -->
                    <mu2>${friction_mu2}</mu2>
                    <!-- value range 0.0 to 1.0 -->
                </ode>
            </friction>
            <contact>
                <ode>
                    <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
                    <kp>1e9</kp>
                </ode>
            </contact>
        </surface>
    </gazebo>
</xacro:macro>

But sadly the parameters either take not effect or I am not correctly using them. I tried mu1 and mu2 in the range of 0.5-0.7 as given by the reference linked in the classic Gazebo documentation and very high mus with 50+, but neither seem to have a huge impact on driving behavior. I also tried using the WheelSlip Plugin from Gazebo, but that didn't have a huge impact either. I had a look at the Prius on Sonoma Raceway example world, but the car in this example also skids heavily on the ground.
I know that I can't expect super precise tire force simulation in Gazebo, but I would at least like to achieve a high friction contact between the tires and the ground.
Am I using these parameters correctly and are there better way to model a car driving on normal asphalt?
Edit 1:
I fixed the indentation of the wheel macro and added the SDF of the whole world.
Whole World SDF:
<sdf version='1.10'>
  <world name='empty'>
    <physics name='phys' type='dart'>
      <max_step_size>0.002</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
    </physics>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Physics' filename='gz-sim-physics-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::UserCommands' filename='gz-sim-user-commands-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster' filename='gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system'/>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Sensors' filename='gz-sim-sensors-system'>
      <render_engine>ogre2</render_engine>
    </plugin>
    <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::Imu' filename='gz-sim-imu-system'/>
    <scene>
      <shadows>false</shadows>
      <grid>false</grid>
      <origin_visual>false</origin_visual>
      <ambient>0.400000006 0.400000006 0.400000006 1</ambient>
      <background>0.699999988 0.699999988 0.699999988 1</background>
    </scene>
    <gravity>0 0 -9.8000000000000007</gravity>
    <magnetic_field>5.5644999999999998e-06 2.2875799999999999e-05 -4.2388400000000002e-05</magnetic_field>
    <atmosphere type='adiabatic'/>
    <model name='ground_plane'>
      <static>true</static>
      <link name='link'>
        <collision name='collision'>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <friction>
              <ode>
                <mu>100</mu>
                <mu2>50</mu2>
              </ode>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
            <contact/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='visual'>
          <geometry>
            <plane>
              <normal>0 0 1</normal>
              <size>100 100</size>
            </plane>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <ambient>0.800000012 0.800000012 0.800000012 1</ambient>
            <diffuse>0.800000012 0.800000012 0.800000012 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.800000012 0.800000012 0.800000012 1</specular>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>1</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>1</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>1</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <self_collide>false</self_collide>
    </model>
    <model name='vehicle'>
      <link name='base_link'>
        <inertial>
          <pose>-0.98300612664473686 0 0.30140446885964911 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>182.40000000000001</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>37.122141546765462</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0.00083158163982943734</ixz>
            <iyy>76.01281949145411</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>82.64280294468864</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__chassis_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.5 0.5 0.10000000000000001</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__chassis_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <mesh>
              <scale>1 1 1</scale>
              <uri>file://<urdf-string>/model://data/ft24_chassis_scaled_decimated.obj</uri>
            </mesh>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/White</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>0.941250026 0.941250026 0.941250026 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>0.941250026 0.941250026 0.941250026 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__laser_frame_visual_1'>
          <pose>-0.99417500000000003 0 1.0387512000000001 0 0.15707963267948971 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.105 0.13159999999999999 0.065000000000000002</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Red</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>1 0 0 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>1 0 0 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__left_camera_link_visual_2'>
          <pose>-1.026953 -0.032836499999999998 0.99939900000000004 -3.5126940446245191e-18 0.1570796326794896 0.35243608118446706</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.029999999999999999 0.029999999999999999 0.029999999999999999</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Black</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <visual name='base_link_fixed_joint_lump__right_camera_link_visual_3'>
          <pose>-1.026953 0.032836499999999998 0.99939900000000004 3.5126940446245191e-18 0.1570796326794896 -0.35243608118446706</pose>
          <geometry>
            <box>
              <size>0.029999999999999999 0.029999999999999999 0.029999999999999999</size>
            </box>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Black</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>0 0 0 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>0 0 0 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='front_left_steer_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <child>front_left_steer_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-0.50614548307835561</lower>
            <upper>0.50614548307835561</upper>
            <effort>117</effort>
            <velocity>43</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='front_left_steer_link'>
        <pose>2.7745295572145778e-07 0.5999990303461149 7.9734651659002509e-09 1.9669608015635631e-09 -7.0097133874246743e-09 -4.8278967746530473e-07</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.00065833333333333336</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.00065833333333333336</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.00125</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='front_left_steer_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.050000000000000003</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='front_left_steer_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.02</length>
              <radius>0.050000000000000003</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Blue</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>0.25 0.25 1 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>0.25 0.25 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='front_left_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>front_left_steer_link</parent>
        <child>front_left_wheel_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-inf</lower>
            <upper>inf</upper>
            <effort>inf</effort>
            <velocity>inf</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='front_left_wheel_link'>
        <pose>2.7574272642993947e-07 0.59999903129195331 7.973460031118762e-09 1.5707963230701574 -1.0144531230445941 3.1415901041896719</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>6.7999999999999998</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.094625877586666671</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.094625877586666671</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.14391842184</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='front_left_wheel_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='front_left_wheel_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Gray</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>50</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
          <contact>
            <ode>
              <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
              <kp>1e9</kp>
            </ode>
          </contact>
        </surface>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='front_right_steer_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <child>front_right_steer_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-0.50614548307835561</lower>
            <upper>0.50614548307835561</upper>
            <effort>117</effort>
            <velocity>43</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='front_right_steer_link'>
        <pose>-1.8310185900816123e-07 -0.60000096965351168 5.6131124470670812e-09 1.9669602793464359e-09 -7.0097123110694225e-09 -4.8347761660151729e-07</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>1</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.00065833333333333336</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.00065833333333333336</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.00125</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='front_right_steer_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.050000000000000003</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='front_right_steer_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.02</length>
              <radius>0.050000000000000003</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Blue</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
            <diffuse>0.25 0.25 1 1</diffuse>
            <ambient>0.25 0.25 1 1</ambient>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='front_right_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>front_right_steer_link</parent>
        <child>front_right_wheel_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-inf</lower>
            <upper>inf</upper>
            <effort>inf</effort>
            <velocity>inf</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='front_right_wheel_link'>
        <pose>-1.8327772277615395e-07 -0.60000096929351621 5.6131125303338081e-09 1.5707963208788129 1.2318665927091217 3.14159136946687</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>6.7999999999999998</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.094625877586666671</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.094625877586666671</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.14391842184</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='front_right_wheel_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='front_right_wheel_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Gray</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>50</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
          <contact>
            <ode>
              <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
              <kp>1e9</kp>
            </ode>
          </contact>
        </surface>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='rear_left_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>-2.2204460492503131e-16 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <child>rear_left_wheel_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-inf</lower>
            <upper>inf</upper>
            <effort>100</effort>
            <velocity>628</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='rear_left_wheel_link'>
        <pose>-1.5750000000000011 0.59999999999999998 0 -1.570796326794893 1.3421121354619261 3.1833134754349777e-15</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>6.7999999999999998</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.094625877586666671</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.094625877586666671</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.14391842184</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='rear_left_wheel_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='rear_left_wheel_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Gray</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>50</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
          <contact>
            <ode>
              <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
              <kp>1e9</kp>
            </ode>
          </contact>
        </surface>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <joint name='rear_right_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
        <pose>-2.2204460492503131e-16 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <parent>base_link</parent>
        <child>rear_right_wheel_link</child>
        <axis>
          <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
          <limit>
            <lower>-inf</lower>
            <upper>inf</upper>
            <effort>100</effort>
            <velocity>628</velocity>
            <stiffness>100000000</stiffness>
            <dissipation>1</dissipation>
          </limit>
          <dynamics>
            <spring_reference>0</spring_reference>
            <spring_stiffness>0</spring_stiffness>
            <damping>0</damping>
            <friction>0</friction>
          </dynamics>
        </axis>
      </joint>
      <link name='rear_right_wheel_link'>
        <pose>-1.5750000000000002 -0.60000000000000009 2.7755575615628914e-17 1.5707963267948917 1.2870327703702786 3.1415926535897882</pose>
        <inertial>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <mass>6.7999999999999998</mass>
          <inertia>
            <ixx>0.094625877586666671</ixx>
            <ixy>0</ixy>
            <ixz>0</ixz>
            <iyy>0.094625877586666671</iyy>
            <iyz>0</iyz>
            <izz>0.14391842184</izz>
          </inertia>
        </inertial>
        <collision name='rear_right_wheel_link_collision'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <surface>
            <contact>
              <ode/>
            </contact>
            <friction>
              <ode/>
            </friction>
            <bounce/>
          </surface>
        </collision>
        <visual name='rear_right_wheel_link_visual'>
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <geometry>
            <cylinder>
              <length>0.20000000000000001</length>
              <radius>0.20574000000000001</radius>
            </cylinder>
          </geometry>
          <material>
            <script>
              <name>Gazebo/Gray</name>
              <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            </script>
          </material>
        </visual>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>50</mu>
              <mu2>50</mu2>
            </ode>
          </friction>
          <contact>
            <ode>
              <min_depth>0.01</min_depth>
              <kp>1e9</kp>
            </ode>
          </contact>
        </surface>
        <enable_wind>false</enable_wind>
      </link>
      <plugin name='gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin' filename='gz_ros2_control-system'>
        <parameters>/home/driverless/eduroam_as/ros2_ws/install/eduroam_control/share/eduroam_control/config/ft24_config.yml</parameters>
      </plugin>
      <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::WheelSlip' filename='gz-sim-wheel-slip-system'>
        <wheel link_name='front_right_wheel_link'>
          <slip_compliance_lateral>0</slip_compliance_lateral>
          <slip_compliance_longitudinal>0.1</slip_compliance_longitudinal>
          <wheel_normal_force>100</wheel_normal_force>
          <wheel_radius>0.20574</wheel_radius>
        </wheel>
        <wheel link_name='front_left_wheel_link'>
          <slip_compliance_lateral>0</slip_compliance_lateral>
          <slip_compliance_longitudinal>0.1</slip_compliance_longitudinal>
          <wheel_normal_force>100</wheel_normal_force>
          <wheel_radius>0.20574</wheel_radius>
        </wheel>
        <wheel link_name='rear_right_wheel_link'>
          <slip_compliance_lateral>0</slip_compliance_lateral>
          <slip_compliance_longitudinal>0.1</slip_compliance_longitudinal>
          <wheel_normal_force>80</wheel_normal_force>
          <wheel_radius>0.20574</wheel_radius>
        </wheel>
        <wheel link_name='rear_left_wheel_link'>
          <slip_compliance_lateral>0</slip_compliance_lateral>
          <slip_compliance_longitudinal>0.1</slip_compliance_longitudinal>
          <wheel_normal_force>80</wheel_normal_force>
          <wheel_radius>0.20574</wheel_radius>
        </wheel>
      </plugin>
      <plugin name='gz::sim::systems::PosePublisher' filename='gz-sim-pose-publisher-system'>
        <publish_link_pose>true</publish_link_pose>
        <publish_collision_pose>true</publish_collision_pose>
        <publish_visual_pose>true</publish_visual_pose>
        <publish_nested_model_pose>true</publish_nested_model_pose>
        <publish_model_pose>true</publish_model_pose>
        <update_frequency>-1</update_frequency>
      </plugin>
      <frame name='laser_joint' attached_to='chassis'>
        <pose>-0.99417500000000003 0 1.0387512000000001 0 0.15707963267948971 0</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='laser_frame' attached_to='laser_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='left_camera_optical_joint' attached_to='left_camera_link'>
        <pose>0 0 0 -1.5707963267948959 -5.5511151231257827e-17 -1.5707963267948959</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='left_camera_link_optical' attached_to='left_camera_optical_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='left_camera_joint' attached_to='chassis'>
        <pose>-1.026953 -0.032836499999999998 0.99939900000000004 -1.0538082133873557e-17 0.1570796326794896 0.35243608118446718</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='chassis_joint' attached_to='base_link'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </frame>
      <frame name='chassis' attached_to='chassis_joint'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      </frame>
      <pose>-5.9052175993439908 0.90056313881770655 0.20573997587822102 -1.9669576473048599e-09 5.529979945706782e-09 -0.10138635069491039</pose>
      <static>false</static>
      <self_collide>false</self_collide>
    </model>
    <light name='sun' type='directional'>
      <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
      <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
      <intensity>1</intensity>
      <direction>-0.5 0.10000000000000001 -0.90000000000000002</direction>
      <diffuse>0.800000012 0.800000012 0.800000012 1</diffuse>
      <specular>0.200000003 0.200000003 0.200000003 1</specular>
      <attenuation>
        <range>1000</range>
        <linear>0.01</linear>
        <constant>0.90000000000000002</constant>
        <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
      </attenuation>
      <spot>
        <inner_angle>0</inner_angle>
        <outer_angle>0</outer_angle>
        <falloff>0</falloff>
      </spot>
    </light>
  </world>
</sdf>


Thanks for the tip! I edited the question and fixed the indentation.

I haven't worked with tires or wheels in gazebo much but for friction properties to work properly both the tire and the surface it is driving on need to have friction properties defined. Is there a road model that you have or are you driving on the ground plane model?
More info in this tutorial.

Yes, I edited the question and included the whole world. I simply added a ground plane and some very high mu and mu2 for the ground plane.
